# Removing reputated words from data frame

Tags: r

I have data frame text file which is tidy text. I want to remove one word from there with the following code

`Words` is the name of the column, `wordtoremove` is the word that I remove from the data.

```
data[! grep("wordtoremove", data$words) , ]
```

This returns `0 rows` however when I look at my data I see that `wordtoremove` still there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `grepl` instead of `grep` for negate (`!`) to work as `grep` returns only the numeric index of the matched pattern while `grepl` returns a logical (`TRUE/FALSE`) vector.  With negation (`!`), the TRUE/FALSE is flipped to `FALSE/TRUE`

```
data[! grepl("wordtoremove", data$words) , ]
```

---

Or user `invert = TRUE` in the `grep` to get the index of the unmatched patterns

```
data[ grep("wordtoremove", data$words, invert = TRUE) , ]
```

Comment: thanks, I run as you said, the function seems to work however `wordtoremove` still there, which is quite amazing.

Comment: @dasurschn  Have you assigned the subset to new data or to the same data `data <- data[! grepl("wordtoremove", data$words) , ]` and if it is a factor.  use `droplevels` as well to wrap to remove the unused levels